# Combining Arithmetic Equations in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, division, multiplication, subtraction

I'm having a lot of issues attempting to implement functions into Assembly Winx64 as a beginner with basic commands such as MOV, ADD and DIV. My goal is to perform this equation into Assembly:

Z = (X/7) - (Y/3)

I had changed the formula in order to equate Z to one term:

Z = (3X - 7Y)/21

The code I do have at the moment, looking at it, has many issues in my mind. Doing multiplication, subtraction and division in the same code in Assembly is a difficulty for me as opposed to having only two terms to add, multiply, subtract or divide.

```
TITLE DISPLAY
      .MODEL SMALL
      .386
      .STACK
      .DATA
X     SBYTE 4, 16, 28, 88, 100, -116, -68, -104, -92, 40, 52, -128, -80, -8, 64, 76, -56, -44, -32, -20
Y     SWORD 32765, -16373, -19651, -22927, 29491, 7, -3271, 26215, 6559, 16387, 13111, 9835,
3283, -6545, -9823, -13099, 22937, 19663, -26201, -29479
Z     DWORD lengthof Y dup (0)

      .CODE
MAIN  PROC FAR
      .STARTUP
      ;Program
      MOV AX, @DATA
      MOV DX, AX
      MOV SI, OFFSET X
      MOV DI, OFFSET Y
      MOV CX, LENGTHOF X 

L1:   MOV AX,0
      MOV BX,0
      MOV AX,[SI]
      MOV BX,3
      MUL BX
      MOV BX,AX
      MOV AX,[DI]
      MOV DX,7
      MUL DX
      SUB BX,AX
      MOV AX,BX
      MOV BX,21
      IDIV BX
      ADD SI,TYPE X
      ADD DI,TYPE Y
      LOOP L1
      .EXIT 
MAIN  ENDP
      END
```

Here is an Excel excerpt on the expected values of Z.

[image]

Comment: For *integer* division (like you're doing), that transformation changes the results.  e.g. `int(5/7) - int(11/3) = -3`.  But `int((3*5 - 7*11)/21)` is `-2`.  The rounding toward 0 that's part of integer division can't be ignored if you want to get the same value as the original expression.  Look at compiler output for your original expression (or for a loop over those arrays) for an example of how you could implement it.

Comment: @PeterCordes So I had revised the code and fixed the Excel sheet because the math was all screwed. I feel like I'm getting there, but I'm still a little lost on how to confirm that this is correct because the value of Z (hex) does not appear in the register when X = 4 and Y = 32765.

Comment: Oh, if you need to support large inputs, that's another reason this transformation doesn't work unless you use 32-bit operand-size.  `32765 * 7` overflows a 16-bit register, and you're ignoring the high half of the DX:AX mul result.  zero- or sign-extend to 32-bit and then `imul eax, edx, 7` for example to do `eax = edx*7`.  You're on a .386 so you can use this.  Or do the two divisions first so you avoid wrapping.